# Swift IAP subscription processing all transactions

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a question in IAP subscription processing in swift.
I am using IAP subscription in my app, the logic works perfectly and i have no issues. I would like to check on processing the transactions from paymentQueue. I notice that it is looping all the transactions from paymentQueue and i have to verify the receipt for all transactions . Is this necessary to loop and check all the transactions, or should i just focus on the last transaction. Will the last transaction be the most recent one. Below is code snippet for the portion of code.

In the output console, I get the following Lines (Last three lines are looping 140 times):
Total Transaction Count - 140

Start refreshing reciept...

Inside Parsing Reciept....

Transaction Purchased

Question: Is it necessary to process all the transactions (140 in this example) This 140 is for the same product. Any way i can avoid this looping, so that it improves processing.

Thanks in advance.

```
extension IAPManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        
        print(" Total Transaction Count -  \(queue.transactions.count)")
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                notifyIsPurchased(transaction: transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                print ("Transaction Purchased")
                break
            case .failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                self.failureBlock?(transaction.error)
                cleanUp()
                break
            case .restored:
                notifyIsPurchased(transaction: transaction)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                print("restored")
                break
            case .deferred:
                print("defered")
                break
            case .purchasing:
                print("purchasing")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private func notifyIsPurchased(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        refreshSubscriptionsStatus(callback: {
            self.successBlock?()
            self.cleanUp()
        }) { (error) in
            // couldn't verify receipt
            self.failureBlock?(error)
            self.cleanUp()
        }
    }

    func refreshSubscriptionsStatus(callback : @escaping SuccessBlock, failure : @escaping FailureBlock) {
        
        print("Start refreshing reciept...")
        self.refreshSubscriptionSuccessBlock = callback
        self.refreshSubscriptionFailureBlock = failure
        
        guard let receiptUrl = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {
            print("No reciept")
            refreshReceipt()
            return
        }
        
        let urlString = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        //let urlString = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptUrl).base64EncodedString()
        let requestData = ["receipt-data" : receiptData ?? "", "password" : self.sharedSecret, "exclude-old-transactions" : true] as [String : Any]
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestData, options: [])
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)  { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if data != nil {
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments){
                    //print (json)
                    self.parseReceipt(json as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
                    return
                }
            } else {
                print("error validating receipt: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }
            self.refreshSubscriptionFailureBlock?(error)
            self.cleanUpRefeshReceiptBlocks()
        }
        }.resume()
    }

    private func parseReceipt(_ json : Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        
        print("Inside Parsing Reciept....")
        
        
        guard let receipts_array = json["latest_receipt_info"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] else {
            self.refreshSubscriptionFailureBlock?(nil)
            self.cleanUpRefeshReceiptBlocks()
            return
        }

        process the receipt array and check if it is expired or valid...

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% guarantee that last transaction in your `[SKPaymentTransaction]` is your most recent transaction according to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506107-paymentqueue) where is written that  `transactions` property is:

> An array of the transactions that were updated.

It is not clearly stated there that `transactions` are properly sorted, although arrays are usually used for elements where order matters.. However you can easily sort your transactions yourself by accessing `transactionDate` property. Here is an example:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                      updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        let ascendingTransactions = transactions.filter({$0.transactionDate != nil})
                                                .sorted(by: {$1.transactionDate! > $0.transactionDate!})
        let latestTransaction = ascendingTransactions.last
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr.SwiftOak . Let me try this and get back. If this solution works for me as expected. This will be issue only when i have large number of transactions… will check and get back.  Thx

Comment: This works in getting the recent transaction… solution works for now. Thx…